# Python "in" keyword is raising KeyError

Tags: python, todoist

In order to check the existence of a key in a `TodoistAPI` class I use the "in" keyword. However, it causes a `KeyError`.

I isolated the code fragments to check what exactly causes the `KeyError` and which inputs are provided.

```py
api = TodoistAPI(token)
api.sync()
print("id" in api.state["items"][0])
```

`api.state["items"][0]` contains:

```
Item({'assigned_by_uid': None,
 'checked': 0,
 'child_order': 0,
 'collapsed': 0,
 'content': 'example task',
 'date_added': '0',
 'date_completed': None,
 'day_order': 0,
 'due': {'date': '0',
         'is_recurring': True,
         'lang': 'de',
         'string': 'every day',
         'timezone': None},
 'has_more_notes': False,
 'id': 0,
 'in_history': 0,
 'is_deleted': 0,
 'labels': [0, 0],
 'parent_id': None,
 'priority': 1,
 'project_id': 0,
 'responsible_uid': None,
 'section_id': None,
 'sync_id': None,
 'user_id': 0})
```

I expect the output of `print(...)` to be `True` or `False`, but the actual output is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/path/to/file.py", line 11, in 
print("id" in applicationInterface.state["items"][0])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/todoist/models.py", line 16, in __getitem__
return self.data[key]
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also created an issue in the Todoist Github-Repository: https://github.com/Doist/todoist-python/issues/64

Comment: Could you `print` the list `api.state["items"]`? I wonder what's inside.

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3 -  Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you got the issue cleared, kindly close the Github Jira Issue.

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3, could you split the statement into two statements, like this:  `item = api.state["items"][0]; print("id" in item)`?  It really seems like the KeyError is reporting a key of `0`.

Comment: @NicholasM `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/path/to/file.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("id" in item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/todoist/models.py", line 16, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key]
KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this is a bug in the `Todoist` library.

First, lets imagine an additional line like this:

```
item = api.state["items"][0]
print("id" in item)
```

This means that when you write `"id" in item`, Python checks for a `__contains__` method in the class.   The `Item` class does *not* define  `__contains__`, but does define `__getitem__` (through its base `Model`).

According to the Python language reference, [`__getitem__` will be called](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) to evaluate the `in`, using *a fallback to a sequence protocol*.

I think the logic used to evaluate `"id" in item` is equivalent to this:

```
## Implicit logic used to evaluate `"id" in item`
for i in itertools.count():
    try:
        result = item[i]
    except IndexError:
        return False

    if result is "id" or result == "id":
        return True
return False
```

Within the evaluation of `Model.__getitem__`, a KeyError is raised.  At a fundamental level, if `Model` is a mapping type, I think it should implement `__contains__` as well as `__getitem__`.  The [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) says this:

> It is recommended that both mappings and sequences implement the `__contains__()` method to allow efficient use of the `in` operator; for mappings, `in` should search the mapping’s keys

Comment: I used `0` just to access the first item in the list returned from the server. I edited my question and inserted how the first item looks like when calling `print(applicationInterface.state["items"][0])`.